# Infinity.js - Issues with rendering inline-block elements & a grandpa container with defined height

Tags: infinity.js

I've been trying to integrate infinity inside a defined scrolled area.
My UI is a bunch of **inline-block** thumbnails (not floated). Grid Layout.

Infinity works perfect inside my page when it occupy the whole page width & height, and each element is block level, with simple DOM inside.

But when create a little more advanced UI, with grid interface, and an infinity area to scroll inside a container (ListView's height isn't defined. It's container does), then all gets wrong. 
Even more than that. If I give 100% to HTML & Body, infinity fails. it calculates wrong listView`s height.

How to solve this? Grid UI is a desired & common one.

**JS Fiddle Demos**:

- [All 1300 elements are block-level -](http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/J2ZE3/8/) #OK
- [ListItem (CSS) Width & Height defined -](http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/J2ZE3/9/) #OK
- [ListItem as inline-block -](http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/J2ZE3/10/)  #Broken

Code Example (Infinity NG Integration)

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demo", []);

demoApp.controller("demoCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 1300; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({ title: "Item " + i });
    }
});

demoApp.directive("infinityScroll", function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, $attrs) {
            scope.listView = new infinity.ListView($(elm));
        }
    };
});

demoApp.directive("infinityItem", function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.listView.append(element);
        }
    }
});
```

PostScript: I noticed in the API Reference, that ListItem has width & Height properties. Same as ListView.
I couldn't find how to implement it, Inside the build code itself, i haven't seen how to pass this properties to the object. 
Sorry if its obvious thing, and its possible to do that.

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually right now I discovered my problem.
2 elements that messed up with my UI where actually - Overflow:Hidden for my Body,HTML, and Height:100% for a page container.

I have removed Overflow:Hidden, and Height from the page container (not ListView!) and all is fine.

'useElementScroll:true' and .scrollable classname did not assisted me, and prevented me from needing do this actions.

Now my UI is impacted, and I need to see how I`ll solve it.

**Edit:**

I have opened an issue at airbnb git, and I hope they will pay attention to this. Not been able to set a father and relate only to him, is an issue that adds complexity.

https://github.com/airbnb/infinity/issues/46